# Rails rendering why have to call .to_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I work on a `Rails API`, and I want to render some binary in json. To do that I convert my binary in hex to render it.

So I have

```
#<PlayCard id: 3, card_id: 12, atk: 10, hp: 9, deck_id: nil, game_id: nil, uid: ".dk\x8A", created_at: "2018-06-06 15:17:25", updated_at: "2018-06-06 15:17:25", user_id: 27>
(byebug) play_card.to_json
{"id"=>3, "card_id"=>12, "atk"=>10, "hp"=>9, "deck_id"=>nil, "game_id"=>nil, "uid"=>"2e646b8a", "created_at"=>Wed, 06 Jun 2018 17:17:25 CEST +02:00, "updated_at"=>Wed, 06 Jun 2018 17:17:25 CEST +02:00, "user_id"=>27}
```

My question is about the rendering of my object. With my method `show` I Have no problem but with my method `create` I have to call `my_object.to_json` did you have an idea ? With out the `.to_json` I have a `ActionDispatch::TestResponse` object.

```
def show
  record = PlayCard.find_by(id: params[:id])
  if record.present?
    render json: record.attributes.except('uid'), status: :ok
  else
    render json: {}, status: :no_content
  end
end

def create
  play_card = PlayCardsService.create(play_card_params)
  if play_card.valid?
    render json: play_card.to_json, status: :created
  else
    render json: { status: 'KO', errors: play_card.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

class PlayCardsService

  class << self

    def create(play_card_params)
      PlayCard.create(play_card_params)
    end

  end

end

def to_json(options = {})
  bin = bin_to_hex(self.uid)
  self.uid = nil
  json = self.as_json
  json['uid'] = bin
  json
end

def bin_to_hex(s)
  s.each_byte.map { |b| b.to_s(16).rjust(2,'0') }.join
end
```

SOLUTION:
I have to override `as_json` and not `to_json`. Look the comment of @engineersmnky.

Thanks for your help

Have a nice day,

Comment: Your `PlayCardService` does not seem to implement `as_json`

Comment: @engineersmnky it's work with out a as_json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In show function there is record.attributes, so You get hash after *attributes* method which can be rendered as json. In create function You are rendering activerecord, where you can use *attributes* method too or just convert it with *to_json*. Consider using jbuilder to render json

Comment: Yeah but why `to_json` was call automaticaly on show but not on create ?

Comment: look here:
https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render
in Rendering JSON part:
"It’s not necessary to call to_json on the object you want to render, since render will automatically do that for you"

Comment: Yeah but I have to do on my object but not on my hash I don't understand

Comment: ActiveRecord is a complex object and i think to_json is necessary to give option of overwriting serialization procedure (as_json method in model definition)

Comment: `to_json` will use `as_json` to define the structure you should write a custom `as_json` not a custom `to_json` then it should render appropriately without the explicit call